# Kernel socket on MAC Lion

Tags: macos, sockets, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

I have an existing code which runs perfectly fine in Mac Snow Leopard OS. However, the same code throws exception while creating the socket. Here is the snippet for same -

`int gSocket = socket(PF_SYSTEM, SOCK_STREAM, SYSPROTO_CONTROL);`

Thereafter, am checking the status of gSocket if negative I throw an exception. This code does not throws exception on MAC Snow Leopard, however, if I run same on Lion OS it throws exception.

I have googled and found something related to sandboxing. However, I dont think this can be related to sandboxing my application, since I do not publish it in the Appstore.

Any thought why a socket for kernel is not opening on Lion?

Thanks,
VijayKumar Dogra

Comment: And what is the value of `errno` when `gSocket < 0`?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?  I suspect not as you state "the same code throws exception...".

Comment: Well I am new to this term sandboxed? do you mean to say Did I used sandbox_init() anywhere in my code? Well then no. If you mean to ask something else, then can you please elaborate more?

Comment: You would have known if you sandboxed the app; you can do it using a checkbox in the Xcode Project settings.  I have briefly looked at the Apple reference relating to `PF_SYSTEM` but couldn't see anything obvious.  I would contact Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) - you have 2 free incidents with your Developer enrollment.